# ¿Cómo mandar la información de un form de HTML a un CrudController?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quiero guardar la información de un `form` de HTML, en la base de datos, a través de mi `CrudController`.

Pero no he sabido cómo hacerlo, las variables de mi `form` se llaman igual que en mi base de datos y todo.

Este es mi archivo `blade`.

```html
<form method="POST" action="/save_design">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre del diseño">
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

Y me confunde un poco las rutas, no sé si debo consultar en `web.php` o en `custom.php`. Lo que hice en `web.php` fue lo siguiente:

```html
<?php

Route::post('/save_design', 'DesignController@setupCreateOperation');
```

Pero tengo errores, como `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DesignCrudController is not invokable.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder almacenar la información que llega de tu formulario yo propongo los siguientes cambios:

Primero en tu mensaje de error noto que tienes esta estructura de carpetas:

```
Controllers
 ----Admin
     ----DesignController
```

Para lograr lo anterior debes ejecutar desde la terminal:

```
php artisan make:controller Admin/DesignController
```

Una vez hecho eso tendrás la ruta de carpetas arriba mencionada

**Modificación de la ruta en tu archivo `web.php`**

Código:

```
Route::get('/save_design/create', 'Admin\DesignController@create')->name('save_design.create');
Route::post('/save_design', 'Admin\DesignController@store')->name('save_design.store');
```

Lo que hice:

- Invoco al nombre del archivo controller precedido por el nombre de la carpeta `Admin` en este caso que lo contiene y una contrabarra `\`
- Agregarle un nombre a la ruta por medio del método `name()`, este mismo nombre será el usado para invocarlo en el `action` del formulario
- El archivo `web.php` almacena tus rutas pero no es el que debes invocar
- Dentro de tu `controller` debes tener al menos estos 2 métodos: `create` y `store`, donde `create` muestra el formulario y `store` procesa la data para almacenarla
- Recomiendo editar el nombre de tu método en el controlador de: **setupCreateOperation** a **store** no solo para mejorar su manejo al tener un nombre mas simple sino además para identificar que operación estamos haciendo

  - `create`: Que nos sirve para mostrar el fomrulario de alta por medio del método `GET`
  - `store`: Que recibirá la data del formulario con ayuda del objeto `$request`que nos ayuda a procesar la data de las peticiones por algún verbo HTTP y en este caso será `POST`

**Modificación del código de tu formulario**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('save_design.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre del diseño">
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
```

Lo que hice fue:

- En el `action` invoco por medio del **helper `route`** al nombre que le di a la ruta que procesará el alta de mi registro
- Debo hacer uso de la directiva de blade `@csrf`

**Ahora en el controlador**

Debería lucir algo parecido a esto:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use App\Modelo;

class DesignController extends BaseController
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('vistaFormulario');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $registroNuevo = new Modelo;
      $registroNuevo->name = $request->input('name');
      ....
      ....
      $registroNuevo->save();
    }
}
```

Lo que hice fue:

- Invoco por su namespace al modelo que me servirá para guardar el registro en la tabla correspondiente, ahí debes colocar el nombre respectivo que tienes tu
- Creo una nueva instancia de dicho modelo asignandolo a un objeto dentro del método `store`
- Con el nuevo objeto `$nuevoRegistro` accedo `->` a la columna deseada por medio de su nombre `name` y posterior obtengo el valor que llego del formulario con ayuda del objeto `$request`
- Leo el valor que llega del `input` por medio de su atributo name que en este caso es `name`
- Por último para hacer el registro de mi nuevo renglón, hago uso del método `save`

Comment: @azeós gracias por la edición, no había notado ese detalle